# MySQL: Limit JOIN results

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have the following tables:

```
order_items
--------------
id     item_id    order_id
1        7          1
2        8          1
3        8          1


items
-------
id     name
2      Parent 2
3      Parent 3
4      Parent 4
7      Thing 7
8      Thing 8
9      Thing 9


item_relationships
-------------------------
child_item_id   parent_item_id
8               3
8               2
8               4
```

What I want to do is to get a count of how many order_items there are, grouped by item_id. In this example, I would want to get back results that show that there is ONE "Thing 7" in the order and TWO "Thing 8" records. The trick here is that I also need to include the FIRST parent's name as well. (First parent = smallest id.) I can do the grouping:

```
SELECT items.name AS orderItemName,
       parentItems.name AS parentItemName,
       COUNT(order_items.id) AS orderItemQty
FROM order_items
  INNER JOIN items ON (items.id = order_items.item_id)
  LEFT JOIN item_relationships ON (item_relationships.child_item_id = items.id)
  LEFT JOIN items AS parentItems ON (parentItems.id = item_relationships.parent_item_id)
WHERE order_items.order_id = 1
GROUP BY order_items.item_id
```

But this will get me:

```
orderItemName    parentItemName    orderItemQty
   Thing 7          (null)           1
   Thing 8          Parent 3         6
```

Whereas I want to get:

```
orderItemName    parentItemName    orderItemQty
   Thing 7          (null)           1
   Thing 8          Parent 2         2
```

In other words, the two things I need to accomplish are:

1. Count the number of like items within a given order
2. Get the name of the first parent for those items

Is this possible *without* some kind of subquery?

Comment: Tables are unordered. What does "first" parent mean? Smallest id value?

Comment: Please edit that into your question, comments are ephemeral & questions should be self-contained.